# tbb - concurrent_vector address to memory?

Tags: vector, concurrency, tbb, concurrent-vector

I'm trying to get a reference to the memory of a `concurrent_vector` in TBB
(Threaded Building Blocks) in a way similar to `std::vector`.

So an `std::vector` would be accessed like: `&stdVector[0]`.

But the equivalent for a `concurrent_vector` doesn't work: `&tbbVector[0]`.

I guess this may have something to do with how the memory is stored internally
in order to be concurrent, but is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unlike std::vector, concurrent_vector does not provide a guarantee of contiguous storage. So taking the address of the first element and doing anything other than accessing the first element is not a good idea.

Comment: Well I have a function that needs a pointer to the data as a parameter - do I have to unload into an array first before passing it along?

Comment: if you need a pointer to a raw array of data, yes you need to copy it. concurrent_vector isn't a raw pointer to data.